# Etale cohomology of projective spaces in the rigid analytic setting

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, motives, rigid-analytic-geometry

Take $K$ a complete non-archimedean field (maybe algebraically closed, to simplify the question), and $\mathbb{P}_K^d$ the rigid projective space over $K$. Can we compute the étale cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{G}_m$ ? Can we also describe the cohomology of the complementary of an arrangement of tubular neighborhood of hyperplans ?

I know that the Voevodsky theory applied to the motive gives a satisfying explicit description for the algebraic projective space. Could there be a similar theory for the rigid case ?

For a less ambitious question, can the étale cohomology groups of degree greater or equal to 2 be of torsion ? It is the case for a large family of algebraic spaces according to a result of Grothendieck. Could it be also true for a more restrictive class of rigid spaces ?

Thanks for any answer